# Switching between Android activities increasing memory usage

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

An app consists of 3 activities: Activity A, B and C. Each activity has "singleTop" set as its launch mode.

All 3 activities just have the default "Hello world!" textview and a button. The button in Activity A starts Activity B and the one in Activity B starts Activity C. This is the code I use:

```
    public void startActivityB(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

The button in Activity C just finishes it using `finish()`

I know there are similar questions but I have tried every single thing to make this work properly but nothing has worked for me. The problem is that if I navigate from A to B , from B to C, then from C to B and finally from B to A using Android's BACK button, and repeat this process several times, for some reason there are several instances of each activity, except A, running. I used MAT to check this and there are several objects of each class when there should only be 1 of each.

My concern with this happening is that the memory my app uses keeps increasing so this will end in my app getting an "OOM" error.

Am I doing something wrong or just missing something?

Activity A

```
package com.test.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class A extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    }

    public void startActivityB(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Activity B

```
package com.test.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class B extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    }

    public void startActivityC(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Activity C

```
package com.test.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class C extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);
    }

    public void closeActivity(View v){
        finish();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Activities still have several instances when changing their launch mode and starting them with different intent flags. For some reason even if I call finish() on the activities the problem persists.

Comment: Please post `ActivityB` and `ActivityC`.

Comment: The action bar back button behaves weirdly for me sometimes. Can you try adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to each of your activity in the manifest and check if you still have multiple instances?

Comment: @Naveed I am not using the action bar, this are just default activities with a method for each button. Also, I specified at the beginning of my post that all 3 activities have "singleTop" as their launch mode.

Comment: I think you should use `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. It's a very confusing attribute and I would recommend looking at [this](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) article to differentiate.

Comment: @AaronGillion I used "singleInstance" before with no success. I just tried with "singleTask" and the problem persists. Several instances are created (according to MAT) and memory continues to increase when switching between activities.

Comment: Well you definitely don't call the `finish()` keyword after you're done with Activities A & B... what device are you testing on? If on an emulator, try testing on a real device?

Comment: @AaronGillion Testing on a real device, Moto X 2014 with Android 4.4. I'm not calling finish() on Activities A and B because I want the BACK button to work between C and B, B and A. I know I could call finish() and then override the behaviour of the BACK button to do this, but I do call finish() in Activity C and there are still several instances of it.

Comment: I'm also wondering why the ram usage is increasing after switching between the activitys... I guess that the garbage collector doesn't remove the old instances when you switch the activitys. Due this you create everytime new instances. But that's only a speculation!